# Displaying reports and Dashboards for Community User

Tags: community, site.com

I have created a community user and I have given a case object for that user where he can login and submit a case, Here user wants to know all the cases he has created and their stages in dashboards. I have this dashboards ready as a system admin i can see but i have a problem in sharing this particular dashboard with community user. Can anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 2):

- Is this a Customer Community? In that case the customer cannot see Dashboards and you will have to do this by creating a List View in the Case tab, or a custom Visualforce page.
- Is this a Partner Community? In that case make sure you put the Report/Dashboard in a report folder that is shared with the right Partner Role